# Trouble with this email attach and PDF?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using code I have found here. I am trying to send a pdf as an attachment but it is not working. I can send the email fine

```
def Email():
    import os
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg.attach(MIMEText(file("John.pdf").read()))



    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com')

    To = ''
    SUBJECT = name
    TEXT = 'This is your bill' '\n' ,int(thesum),\
    'Your total distance is ',int(totalDistance),\
    'Yur best route is '' ,  '.join(root),\

    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    msg = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (SUBJECT, TEXT)


    server.login("", "")

    server.sendmail("",To, msg)
    print('sent')

Email()
```

I get the following error:

```
   msg.attach(MIMEText(file("John.pdf").read()))
   NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Email():
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg.attach(MIMEText("John.pdf"))


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com')

To = ''
SUBJECT = name
TEXT = 'This is your bill' '\n' ,int(thesum),\
'Your total distance is ',int(totalDistance),\
'Yur best route is '' ,  '.join(root),\

server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()

msg = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (SUBJECT, TEXT)


server.login("", "")

server.sendmail("",To, msg.as_string())
print('sent')
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` is not a function.
maybe you want to do something like this:

```
with open('John.pdf', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

and then add `s` as attachement.

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(s))
```

---

(but i am not sure how to use the email related stuff; maybe you have to base64 encode it and use `MIMEApplication()` for pdf files; maybe someone else can answer this for you)

Comment: I have it working to send the name of the PDF, I dont understand how to attach the file. the code you gave doesnt work. This is what I have so far

Comment: the code opens the file and attaches the files content, this is what you want, BUT! you cannot attach a pdf file directly, and you cannot attach it as MIME Text.  you have to encode it in base64 an then attach the base64 string as MIME Application.  but i am far from an expert on this topic, so mayby somebody else can help you with this, or edit my answer.